# Proportionality: $I ∝ V$ or $V ∝ I $, are both of them correct?

Tags: electric-current, voltage, elasticity, stress-strain

I have a simple question that's been on my mind for a while. If both current is proportional to voltage ($I \propto V$) and voltage is proportional to current ($V \propto I$), are they actually saying the same thing, or are they different statements? I have the same question about stress and strain: if stress is proportional to strain (Stress ∝ Strain) and vice versa, is it the same idea or something else?

Comment: Anything that has a proportionality one way has it the other way too. $V\propto I$ means that $\exists k\in\mathbb R^+\ |\qquad V=kI$ which then implies that $I=\frac1k V$ which is equivalent to saying that $I\propto V$

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I'm pretty sure someone asking this question doesn't know the symbols "there exists a k element of the positive reals such that," nor do they know what that means. Naturally inconsistent meant "there is some constant that I will call $k$ where $V=k\times I$

Comment: thank you @naturallyInconsistent

Comment: thank you @AXensen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand this at intuitive level, say you have chart $y=ax$, like:
[image]

So $y \propto x$, now just rotate chart $90^\circ$ clockwise and flip it vertically, getting :

[image]

We see that axis were interchanged, and still proportionality $x \propto y$ applies. Just linear equation slope transforms to $a_{~new} = \frac 1a$.

So the final answer is yes, $x \propto y$ and $y \propto x$ are equivalent statements, because in general math equations measures correlation between parameters, which may or may not involve direct causal relation.

Comment: The $+b$ in your first equation seems like a mistake. If there is a y-intercept that isn't zero, neither $x\propto y$ nor $y\propto x$. Unless of course we only consider big $x$ and low precision measurements of $y$ such that $ax\gg b$.

Comment: It depends how we define proportionality. If it's a condition that $y/x = \text{const}$, then yes, adding y intercept destroys proportionality, cause now $y/x= a+b/x$, i.e. not constant. However, If we consider proportionality to be condition $\frac {dy}{dx} = \text{const}$, then it still applies, because $\frac {d(ax)}{dx}+\frac{db}{dx}=a$. Of course this more reminds correlation factor than proportionality, but I think it's more or less "comparable metrics".

Comment: I've never seen proportionality defined as $\frac{dy}{dx}={\rm const}$. I've only ever seen it defined like on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)); the ratio of two functions is constant, or in this case $\frac{y}{x} = {\rm const}$. That property is key since it implies doubling $x$ will result in doubling $y$. If $b\neq 0$, then $y$ and $x$ are not proportional according to the commonly accepted definition.

Comment: @Andrew I understand that, as I have stated it myself in the comment. However, as y-intercept in the formula adds interesting ideas/problems, I'll leave it in the post.

Comment: Honestly I find that to be a really unfortunate double-down. "Sure that's not a dog, it's a cat. But if I define a dog as a mammal, then a cat _is_ a dog!". You aren't allowed to define things however you feel - proportionality already has a definition, and it doesn't accommodate an intercept. The answer would be great if you just deleted $+b$, but as is I'm giving a downvote.

Comment: Well, I think cats and dogs are not good analogy to mathematics. I thought that math was the only place where you can shuffle axioms on the fly, to get the required functional behavior. But maybe I'm wrong. Removed $b$ for your pleasure 

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas then my downvote becomes an upvote. thanks. good answer.

Answer (score 2):

If a component in an electric circuit obeys Ohm's law then $V \propto I$ (and hence, as you observe, $I \propto V$ also). However, there are many components, such as diodes, LEDs, capacitors and inductors, which do *not* obey Ohm's law. Since Ohm's law does not always apply, it would not be correct to say that voltage and current are basically the same thing.

A similar argument applies to stress and strain. If strain is proportional to stress then a material obeys Hooke's law, and is said to be linear-elastic or "Hookean". However, many materials do not obey Hooke's law, and those that do only obey it for a limited range of stresses. Since Hooke's law is not universal, it would not be correct to say that stress and strain are basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I understand your question: in view of Ohm’s law, are voltage and current actually the same concept?

The answer is that the two concepts are entirely different. Voltage is an energy difference caused on the accumulation of charge, for example by electrochemical effects in a battery. Current on the other hand characterises the motion of charge. In fact, the proportionality is not generally valid. In vacuum charges will accelerat when a voltage difference, hence an electric field, is present and current and voltage are not proportional. In conductive media such as metals or plasmas the charges are also accelerated but at the same time scattered by irregularities such as thermal atomic motion. Under quite general circumstances this leads to the universal behaviour described by Ohm’s law. The charges reach a saturated flow, much like raindrops reach a constant falling velocity and your car reaches a constant speed even though your engine accelerates it.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of proportional does not mean that two things are the same. It means they are related in a particular way.

In this case, $V \propto I$ in a circuit with a power supply and a resistor. $V$ is the energy per electron. $I$ is more or less the number of electrons flowing.

Saying they are proportional means if you turn up the voltage, you get more current. If you seem a bigger current, that means someone has turned up the voltage.